# Salesforce PubSub API rejecting access token

Tags: c#, oauth-2.0, salesforce, grpc, publish-subscribe

I'm attempting to interact with the Salesforce gRPC PubSub API for my Developer instance and receiving the error `An authentication exception occurred. Provide valid authentication via metadata headers`.

I'm supplying the following headers for the gRPC client to the url https://api.pubsub.salesforce.com:7443;

1. `accesstoken` The accesstoken retrieved from my developer instance
2. `instanceurl` `https://blah-dev-ed.develop.my.salesforce.com`
3. `tenantid` `00xxxxxxxxxxxxx`

I can't find anywhere in the documentation what scopes the accesstoken requires. I've tried `api web openid offline_access id` and still get the same error with no further information as to what's wrong.

The access token was obtained using code exchange flow with the login url https://blah-dev-ed.develop.lightning.force.com/services/oauth2/authorize and token url https://login.salesforce.com/services/oauth2/token

I'm unsure if I don't have the right scopes or I'm getting urls mixed up for the developer instance. Is there a different pubsub url when using a developer instance?

Comment: Unfamiliar with Salesforce gRPC but the error suggests you're incorrectly providing the metadata headers and you don't include (please add to your question) your client code that does this. See [Authentication](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/platform/pub-sub-api/guide/supported-auth.html) and [Include Headers in RPC calls](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/platform/pub-sub-api/guide/rpc-method-headers.html)

Comment: So this works with a token obtained via password grant type. I have no idea if tokens obtained with code exchange are valid for the pub/sub api or there's some scope/configuration I need to make them work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seemingly the pubsub api doesn't work with JWT access tokens, only opaque access tokens. I had to disable `Issue JSON Web Token (JWT)-based access tokens` in my Connected App. You also don't need to include a scope when obtaining a token.